# How do I compare the performance of Node.js to that of PHP on Apache

Tags: php, node.js

this might have been asked many times but, I want the specific performance testing methodology. I am having second thoughts on porting my application from PHP to Node.js since it involves some realtime data. If the performance tests that I make are satisfactory, then I think I will introduce some new modules which include realtime data.

Please can anyone help me with the task of how to test the performance.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this question has been asked already. But since you ask "how" it's done, you might want to use Apache Utilities which can be used to benchmark the performance. [This article](http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-nodejs-basic-performance-tests-against-apache-php) walks through how one person used 'ab' to generate traffic, and dstat to monitor cpu and memory.